# Problema con node js

Tags: nodejs

tengo un problema instalando express en un proyecto y me aparece el siguiente aviso:

```
$ npm install express
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open'C:\nodeprojects\panolsoft\package.json'

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\nodeprojects\panolsoft\package.json'

npm WARN panolsoft No description

npm WARN panolsoft No repository field.

npm WARN panolsoft No README data

npm WARN panolsoft No license field.
```

que debería hacer?

Comment: Antes de empezar a instalarle paquetes a un nuevo proyecto, haz `npm init` para crear un `package.json` siguiendo el wizard en la consola

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta